# ListView items hide behind the EditText. Need whatsapp like chat activity

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, whatsapp

I am having trouble in my layout implementation. Whenever I click on the edittext the softinput keyboard appears and hides the listview items, what i need is that whenever soft keyboard pops up and if the listview's last item is visible, it should be brought above the edit text, if its not visible, the list should remain the way it is (the same way it is in whatsapp), heres my layout code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/bg_other" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/line_separator"
    android:layout_below="@+id/actionbar_toolbar"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:stackFromBottom="true" >
</ListView>

<View 
    android:id="@+id/line_separator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ll_editText"
    android:background="#1F000000"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/message_hint"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color"
        android:maxLines="4" />

    <View 
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="#1F000000"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Button_send"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/cherry_send"
        android:textColor="@color/orange"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ll_editText"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="#A0000000"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
    android:text="2 new messages"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have used window:softInputMode as adjustResize in my manifest for the activity, since using adjustPan hides the editText behind soft keyboard in some cases.
Please suggest how I can achieve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution....

```
mListView.setTransctiptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_NORMAL);
```

did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Try LinearLayou something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:stackFromBottom="true" >
    </ListView>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line_separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#1F000000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_editText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="text"
            android:maxLines="4" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="#1F000000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Button_send"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="#A0000000"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:text="2 new messages"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for commenting.... I already tried using linear layout but to no use..... the edit text still gets on top of listview..... I feel it might be because of the Button btn_Button i am using to show new messages which appears above the edit text linear layout...... cant find a way to solve that issue